# mediaelement.js Multiple videos on same page?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm trying to put multiple videos up on a page, however when I click on one to play, they all play? Has anyone else experienced this?

Heres a snippet of the code im using

```
$("video,audio").mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (player, node) {
        player.pause();
    }
});

$('.mag_video .overlay_exit, .mag_video .overlay_bg').live('click', function () {
    var _this = this;
    $("video,audio").each(function () {
        $(this)[0].player.pause();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an option available to disable this behavior which is named 'pauseOtherPlayers', setting it to false will allow you to play multiple videos at the same time.

I adapted your exemple code :

```
$("video,audio").mediaelementplayer({
    pauseOtherPlayers: false,
    success: function (player, node) {
      player.pause();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your jQuery selector is selecting *all* videos on the page. You want something more specific like:

```
$('#video1').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (player, node) {
        player.pause();
    }
});


$('#video2').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (player, node) {
        player.pause();
    }
});
```