# How to create two players using MediaElement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-player

I am new to Javascript and jQuery. 
I want to create two players using MediaElement.js. One player will play audio and another will play video.
Anyone please help me to do so.
I have tried to run them by using  both jQuery and Javascript code together, but I found that only one is working at a time.

Please provide any sample code also, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I found this question useful to my question  [mediaelement.js Multiple videos on same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971874/mediaelement-js-multiple-videos-on-same-page)  .  Key point is to   **set      *pauseOtherPlayers: false***,   while creating instance of player. This will not pause any other player when other player starts.

I have created two players and played them simultaneously by following code.

```
Player-1:  
if (this.MEplayer != undefined && this.MEplayer) {
            this.setvideosize();
            this.video.play();
            return;
        }


    this.MEplayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#overlayplayer', {
        pluginPath: '../js/me281/',
        flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
        silverlightName: 'silverlightmediaelement.xap',
                pauseOtherPlayers: false,
        defaultVideoWidth: $.viewer.player_width, 
        defaultVideoHeight: $.viewer.player_height,
        videoWidth: $.viewer.player_width, 
        videoHeight: $.viewer.player_height,
        enableAutosize: false,
        debug: false, 
        features: ['playpause', 'progress', 'current', 'duration', 'fullscreen'],
        success: function (me, domobj) {
            console.log('player initiated successfully');
            self.video = me;

            self.state = true;
            self.isTSinitialized = false;
            .....
                    }
```

Repeat the same by changing variable names for other player.